# Which wiki toolkit has the greatest support for data freedom?

Tags: metadata, sharepoint, wiki

Our dev team has poured a lot of knowledge into a Sharepoint wiki. The experience has made me  a convert to the core ideas of a wiki - ease of link/page creation, metadata, search tools, versioning, web standards, etc.

On the other hand, I'm impressed by the associated data lock. It's hard to believe, but I get the impression even Microsoft doesn't have tools to properly migrate a SP wiki between sites or even between SP versions (2007 -> 2010).

Things are worse when one looks at moving data between wiki systems. Few, if any, provide data import/export. Even though many wikis are open source, I don't see any movement towards a common data standard that might support import/export. This is particularly ironic given the "open" orientation of wiki creators.

I fee like I'm missing something. Hence this SU question:

1. Which wiki toolkit has the greatest support for data freedom?
2. Are their initiatives to establish a common data format for wiki content? If so, which wiki support it?

Comment: There is the Wiki Interchange Format, but it seems to never have come out of the idea-stage. Some plugins allow you to capture wiki content as html, but again this is not a complete export/import solution.

Comment: I don't see any initiative to adopt a common data format.  For one, I'm not interested in any company pouring time and money into import/export tools that businesses will use at most once every three years. . .

Comment: Looks like there isn't any interchange standard. That means I can't consider a wiki as my personal knowledge repository.